# Expected ')' before string

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I have tried a lot of different solutions to this problem and I just can't seem to figure out why the compiler continues to give me this error in my header file. If somebody could please give me some insight, that would be very much appreciated. EDIT: Sorry forgot which line is giving the error. It's in the header file the line: Date(string mstr, int dd, int yy);

And yes I know the this = new Date... is a bad solution, I'm just working it out a bit ;)

Header:

```
#include <string>

#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

class Date{
    public:
        Date(int mm, int dd, int yy);
        Date(string mstr, int dd, int yy);
        void print();
        void printFullDate();
        void prompt();

        void setMonth(int);
        void setDay(int);
        void setYear(int);

        int getMonth();
        int getDay();
        int getYear();

        static const int monthsPerYear = 12;
    private:
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;

        int checkDay(int);
};

#endif
```

And here is the implementation if you need it(It's not totally finished, I'm just trying to test out some of the functions I've written):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

Date::Date(int mm, int dd, int yy){
    setMonth(mm);
    setYear(yy);
    setDay(dd);
}

Date::Date(string mstr, int dd, int yy){
    cout << "It's working";
}

int Date::getDay(){
    return day;
}

int Date::getMonth(){
    return month;
}

int Date::getYear(){
    return year;
}

void Date::setDay( int dd ){
    day = checkDay(dd);
}

void Date::setMonth( int mm ){
    if( mm > 0 && mm <= monthsPerYear)
        month = mm;
    else
        throw invalid_argument("month must be 1-12");

}

void Date::setYear( int yy ){
    year = yy;
}

int Date::checkDay( int testDay){
    static const int daysPerMonth[ monthsPerYear + 1 ] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    if( testDay > 0 && testDay <= daysPerMonth[ getMonth() ])
        return testDay;
    if( getMonth() == 2 && testDay == 29 && (getYear() % 400 == 0 || ( getYear() % 4 == 0 && getYear() % 100 != 0 ) ) )
        return testDay;
    throw invalid_argument("Invalid day for current month and year");
}

void Date::print(){

}

void Date::printFullDate(){

}

void Date::prompt(){
    int userChoice = 1;
    int mm, dd, yy;
    string monthStr;

    while(userChoice != 3){
        cout << "Enter 1 for format: MM/DD/YYYY" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 2 for format: Month DD, YYYY" << endl;
        cout << "Enter 3 to exit" << endl;
        cout << "Choice: " << endl;
        cin >> userChoice;
        while(userChoice < 1 || userChoice > 3){
            cout << "Please enter a number 1 - 3 for the formats above." << endl;
            cout << "Choice: " << endl;
            cin >> userChoice;
        }
        if(userChoice != 3){
            switch(userChoice){
                case 1:
                    cout << "Enter Month (1 - 12): ";
                    cin >> mm;
                    setMonth(mm);
                    cout << "Enter Day of Month: ";
                    cin >> dd;
                    setDay(dd);
                    cout << "Enter Year: ";
                    cin >> yy;
                    setYear(yy);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Enter Month Name: ";
                    cin >> monthStr;
                    cout << "Enter Day of Month: ";
                    cin >> dd;
                    cout << "Enter Year: ";
                    cin >> yy;
                    this = new Date(monthStr, dd, yy);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Among the many different solutions you have tried, have you tried adding an `#include <string>` directive?

Comment: Oh, and also using `std::string` rather than just `string` unless you have a `using` declaration

Comment: And this: `this = new Date(monthStr, dd, yy);` is **criminal** :-)

Comment: In the header you need `std::string` instead of `string`

Comment: Okay I fixed the String problem by including     std::string.
Now I have to fix that this = new Date(monthStr, dd, yy); lol

Comment: @user1378664: In my answer I describe also the last fix you need to make your program compile.

Comment: @AndyProwl The `using namespace std` is a sign of a petty criminal too!

Comment: you cant modify **this** pointer. its a constant pointer. check that line in your code. standard forbids it and so should the compiler which follows standard

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Agree ;-)

Comment: @Koushik In a non-`const` member function, it's a `const` pointer to a non-`const` object, so you can modify the contents of the object.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain agreed i dint say one cannot modify a non constant member data through this, i said its not possible to modify *this* itself. i.e object it points to..isint it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Problem #1:** Add an include directive for `string`

```
#include <string>
```

**Problem #2:** Use the fully qualified `std::string` rather than just `string`, or place a using-declaration before your class definition:

```
using std::string;
```

**Problem #3:** You cannot reassign the `this` pointer:

```
this = new Date(monthStr, dd, yy); // ERROR!
```

What you are trying to do should be probably re-written as:

```
*this = Date(monthStr, dd, yy);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I needed! Although using `*this` is still giving me errors. I guess I got some more work to do to get this to work ;P

Comment: @WhozCraig: That would be too generous ;-)

Comment: I'm waiting for it to allow me to accept it! And it's telling me:
`no match for 'operator=' in '*(Date*)this = (std::basic_string<char>((*(const std::basic_string<char>*)(& monthStr))), (operator new(12u), (<statement>, ((Date*)<anonymous>))))'|`

Comment: @user1378664: Is the code different from the one you posted? And did you remove the `new`?

Comment: **facepalm** You are a hero. I need to wake up a bit more, time to grab some more coffee. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you have any extra time, would you mind a brief explanation (or point me to somewhere that can explain it!) on why it is `*this = Date(...);` rather than `this = new Date(...);`?

Comment: @LSavage: the `this` pointer is a pointer to the current object. Even if you could change it, it would not change the object itself, just the pointer. But you can't change it anyway, it is immutable (and you really want it to be so!). In every member function of a class, you know `this` points to the object on which the member function was invoked. On the other hand, `*this` dereferences that pointer to obtain a reference to the current object, and `operator =` is (implicitly) defined for objects of type `Date`. I can't explain any better in a few words, try googling for some tutorial ;)

Comment: That was all the explanation I needed. Again, I need more coffee because it totally went over my head that `this` was a pointer, of course you would have to dereference it to change the contents! Thanks again, you've been a whole lot of help! Have a +1 :)

Comment: @AndyProwl can't you put that `using std::string` *in* the class definition? Its a feature I rarely use in the language so was just curious. Edit: nm. its a namespace. duh.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, I guess you can put it wherever a declaration can be put.

Answer (score 2):

use `std::string` or declare `using namespace std;` at the beginning of the code.